# How can I rename a variable across dozens of files using my Windows laptop?

Tags: windows, rename

I want to do the following using my Windows 7 laptop. I have a project directory. I want to rename the variable MY_APP to SOME_OTHER_APP in all files in the directory and all files in all sub directories. What's the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your IDE supports refactoring, just use it to rename the variable. Most modern IDEs support this.

If not, just do a search-and-replace on all the files in the directory. This will only work if your original variable name is not something commonly found in your code in other contexts (for example, if the variable is 'i' and you have many 'i' local variables as well).